# MySQL over ssh tunnel

Tags: mysql, ssh

I have a very strange problem with SSH Tunnel.
I want to connect to a remote MySQL Server using an SSH Tunnel. 
I have created the tunnel with great success in the past, but for a strange reason it's not OK now. 
The Tunnel is created as:
ssh user@remote.com -T -N -L 6603:localhost:3306.

When I try to connect to the remote MySQL Server, the connection is performed on the **local** MySQL server!

So, I tried to use the ssh user@remote.com -T -N -L 6603:remote.com:3306
which is not what all how-tos say, but what the man page do.

No success :(
Everything that I have tried is not working and now I am really confused. What is wrong with that setup?

Comment: How are you connecting to mysql?

Answer (score 2):

Are you connecting to the server with the -P command line option? Like:

```
 mysql -P 6603 -u user -p
```

Comment: Of course. And to be sure that I don't use the local socket, I use the --protocol tcp option too.

Comment: OK, I found it. 
The problem is that I used the "localhost" which by default it connects to your mysql server though the UNIX socket. So, I should use 127.0.0.1 as I did in the past. Archive logs saved my day.

Comment: Peter, thanks for posting your solution. I was just preparing to ask the same question here, and voila! I tried your suggestion and it worked like a charm. Now if I could just get back the lost hour I wasted, trying to solve it myself...

Answer (score 0):

try:
  ssh -L6603:localhost:3306 ssh user@remote.com

aka, forward all traffic to localhost port 6603 to remove.com port 3306

You would then use host: 'localhost' and port 6603 to connect to server.

You can also check to make sure that the local port is not in use (netstat -tnlp for example) and that 3306 is not being blocked by a firewall.